# Locking a whole row while editing in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with 4 columns that are required.  When a users finishes one cell, they can click out of the row.  I want to force the user to fill in all values before they can continue.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a popup dialog to add a new row of data to the table. Then the dialog "Save" button can check to make sure all four fields are filled in.